# Why does my clothes dryer make a rattling sound after 5 minutes?

Tags: repair, dryer

We have a new dryer just one year old. It's an Amana. Just the other day it suddenly started making loud rattling noise after running  5 min. It's so new I'm surprised. What could this be. Everything else working fine. Just really noisy. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: What model is it?

Answer (score 1):

A dryer is a very simple machine.

There is a belt that turns the drum and there are bearings on the drum supports.The motor, the belt, or the drum bearings can have a problem - the drum bearings is what I suspect.

Sometimes the simple things are overlooked so with that said:

Another possibility is that you have something on the side of the dryer (like a dryer shoe rack) that starts to rattle against the machine after it is spinning up a bit, also check your venting pipes.

Comment: I have replaced the idler rollers on several dryers that would cause noise and because of the worn idler the belt can be a bit loose. I have only had to do this on much older units. I did have a tension spring that applied pressure on the motor to keep the belt tight break one time but this caused the motor to skip at the start when everything was damp.

Answer (score 0):

If it is new and one year old, you should talk to the place where you bought it.

They will either have you bring it in or tell you what to do about it.

What could this be?   First thought is a belt that was installed slightly too loose and gets even looser as it heats up.  Maybe you are hearing it slipping.  Or, perhaps, "rattling" could mean you have lost a ball in one of the bearings.

Either way, talk to the source.

Here's a suggestion.  Use this phrase:  "When I bought it here, I certainly expected it to last longer than one year"

Answer (score 0):

If it’s still “under warranty “, I’d call the manufacturer before you start “messing” with it. You could void the warranty. (And no matter what...unplug it...)

Answer (score 0):

My dryer started doing a similar thing.  The entire drum unit was cracked, probably from my kids climbing into it once.  The drums are just not meant to hold a lot of weight in a single spot.  You can run your fingers on the inside close to the rear and then again in the front, and see if you feel any cracks.